# Como consumo una consulta desde xamarin a sqlserver, con una referencia web?

Tags: sql-server, webservice, xamarin

> Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario escriba un apellido en una casilla de texto, se conecte a SQLServer y traiga el valor que esta en Sql server de vuelta, mediante el servicio web.
>   Cita en bloque

Esta es la conexion con sql server

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet ConsultaAportes(string Apellido)
{
    SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ALIENWARE17-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; " + "Initial Catalog=Software; " + "User ID=sa; Password=123");
    DataSet Conjunto = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter Consulta = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Agentes WHERE Apellido='" + Apellido + "'", Conexion);
    try
    {
        Conexion.Open();
        Consulta.Fill(Conjunto, "Agentes");
        Conexion.Close();
        return Conjunto;
    }
    catch (SystemException)
    {
        Conexion.Close();
        return Conjunto;
    }
}
```

> Esta es mi Main Activity de mi aplicacion de Xamarin

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var btnbuscar = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.btnbuscar );
        var txtnombre = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.txtnombre);
        var txtapellido = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.txtApellido);
        var txtaporte = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.txtaporte);
        var Imagen = FindViewById<ImageView>
            (Resource.Id.imagen);

        btnbuscar.Click += delegate
        {

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la ventaja de seleccionar por qué medio realizarás la petición a tu base de datos , te recomiendo que hagas una web año y hagas tu llamada en Xamarin que serían unas pocas líneas de código .. si necesitas un ejemplo de esta forma te puedo guiar

En esta liga puedes encontrar lo que te comentaba 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: por favor lee [answer], la idea de responder es que como bien mencionas al final agregues un ejemplo para que la respuesta quede mas completa